# how to add svn dummy revisions to resolve my issue of "No such revision 171"

Tags: svn, svn-administraton

I want to change the server of svn but i am unable to dump the repository, its giving me error "No such revision 171". I also tried to dump in parts `svnadmin dump /repos r172:190> home/j/repos.svn_dump` but this command still give error no such revision 171. Please help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`svnadmin help dump`

> Valid options:
>
> -r [--revision] ARG      : specify revision number ARG (or X:Y range)

**`-r 172:190`**

bur `svnadmin verify -r 171` + `svnadmin recover` + reading of [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.html)

will be better way